# Which is better: to edit spelling errors or to ask the OP to do it

Tags: discussion

I see so many questions with spelling and punctuation errors and I sometimes correct them. Is that right or it is better if I ask the one who has written the question/answer to edit it and improve it.

Comment: OP ? can i get its full form

Comment: @Fennekin Sorry for this abbreviation, it is Original poster - the person who asked the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can improve a post, it is best to simply edit it yourself. Users with lower reputation can make *suggested edits* that can be approved later through the review queue. This is at heart of what wiki editing is about in Stack Exchange.

Trying to orchestrate this through comments only leaves a mess behind to clean up later.